# C++ Greatest common divisor loop

Tags: c++

I tried to write a program which shows Greatest common divisor and It doesn't work properly, Could you help me figure where the problem is?
I have to write it by while or do while.

Thanks in advance!

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int num1,num2,mod,div;
    cout<<"Enter 2 numbers:"<<endl;
    cin>>num1>>num2;
    if (num1>=num2)
    {
     do{
        mod=0;
        mod= num1%num2;
        div= num1/num2;
        num1=num2;
        num2=mod;




     }while(mod!=0);
     cout<<div<<endl;
    }
    else if (num2>=num1)
    {
        do{
            mod=0;
            mod= num2%num1;
            div=num2/num1;
            num2=num1;
            num1=mod;


        }while(mod!=0);
        cout<<div<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: What steps have you taken to debug your program? Show your working, and someone might be inclined to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GCD in your logic is not `div` but `num1` in the `if` branch and `num2` in the `else` branch.

Computation of `div` is useless for the final result. It is useful only if you wish to produce debug output.

I recommend creating a function and avoiding duplicated logic.

```
int gcd(int num1, int num2)
{
   int mod = 0;

   if ( num1 < num2 )
   {
      return gcd(num2, num1)
   }

   do {
      mod = num1%num2;
      num1 = num2;
      num2 = mod;
   } while ( mod != 0 );

   return num1;
}
```

and use it from `main` as:

```
int main()
{
    int num1,num2;
    cout<<"Enter 2 numbers:"<<endl;
    cin>>num1>>num2;
    cout << "GCD: " << gcd(num1, num2) << endl;
}
```